# Visualizar no browser arquivo pdf com url no database

Tags: php, html, pdf, navegador-de-internet

Olá!
Possuo uma aplicação que faz o upload do arquivo PDF cuja url está salvo no banco e o arquivo em uma pasta. Ao clicar no botão view o arquivo pdf abre no navegador.

```
<a href="view.php?id= NÃO SEI O QUE COLOCAR AQUI"><button type="button" class="button btn btn-link">View</button></a>
```

Este é meu view.php:

```
  <?php
      header('Content-type: application/pdf');
      echo $row['arquivo']; 
  ?>
```

Não sei o que fazer. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Está fazendo um pouco de confusão no código.

O seu link deve abrir uma URL tipo esta:

http://seusite/view.php?pdf_id=24

Na sua página de exibição view.php:

```
$pdf_id= $_REQUEST['pdf_id']; 
AQUI VAI A CONSULTA SQL para recuperar URL e arquivo.
```

Comment: Como ficará o <a href="view.php?pdf_id= COMO FICARÁ AQUI"><button type="button" class="button btn btn-link">View</button></a>.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.
No caso, meu arquivo view.php ficaria assim? :

```
<?php
  $pdf_id = $_REQUEST['arquivo'];

  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  echo $pdf_id;
?>
```

e meu button como ficaria?

```
<a href="view.php?id= COMO FICARIA AQUI "><button type="button" class="button btn btn-link">View</button></a>
```